# How to use resource for admin routes?

Tags: controller, routes, admin, laravel-5.5

I'm new to laravel. I'm trying to use resource in route for admin sections. I have created web.php like this.

```
Route::get('/' , 'HomeController@index')->name('mainHomePage');


Route::resource('admin','admin\AdminController');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'is.admin'], function () {
    Route::resource('admin.subjects','admin\SubjectsController');
});
```

and my admin controller is within `App/Http/Controllers/admin` directory.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.index');
    }
    public function login($id)
    {
        dd('dlkfjskdjf');
    }
}
```

When I hit route `http://localhost/quizl/admin` the desired view is returned. But when I try `http://localhost/quizl/admin/index` no any view or any error is flashed. Simiarly, I'm unable to hit route http://localhost/quizl/admin/login. Please help me in this.

Comment: you should check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers), Resource controller handles 7 actions. Also i think you are trying to use route prefixes see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-prefixes)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by ab_ab I could solve this issue by using prefix as follows.

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/' , 'HomeController@index')->name('mainHomePage');

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login' , 'admin\AdminController@login')->name('admin.login');
    Route::resource('/','admin\AdminController');
    Route::resource('subjects','admin\SubjectsController');
});
```